# While iterating over the rows in an SQLite table, is it possible to delete the cursor's row?

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, sql-delete, delete-row

I understand you can do `DELETE FROM table WHERE condition`, but I was wondering if there was a more elegant way? Since I'm iterating over every row with `c.execute('SELECT * FROM {tn}'.format(tn=table_name1))`, the cursor is already on the row I want to delete.

Comment: why not try it?

Answer (score 2):

A cursor is a read-only object, and cursor rows are not necessarily related to table rows. So this is not possible.

And you must not change the table while iterating over it.
SQLite computes result rows on demand, so deleting the current row could break the computation of the next row.

Comment: How would you suggest I delete the rows then?

Comment: `DELETE FROM table WHERE condition`, or fetch all rows before iterating.

Comment: "And you must not change the table while iterating over it. SQLite computes result rows on demand, so deleting the current row could break the computation of the next row."

That's not necessarily true. According to the SQLite documentation, 'if an application issues a SELECT statement on a single table like "SELECT rowid, * FROM table WHERE ..." and starts stepping through the output of that statement using sqlite3_step() and examining each row, then it is safe for the application to delete the current row or any prior row using "DELETE FROM table WHERE rowid=?".'

Answer (score 0):

The documentation https://sqlite.org/isolation.html explains what to expect if your application performs updates during the iteration of an open cursor.  Generally: the database won't break, but your query may or may not receive new copies of rows you've updated or deleted.  Some particular operations are documented "safe" from even that level of undefined-behaviour (e.g., delete by rowid of rows already processed).